# Azure AD Graph Explorer - Read all groups permission

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory, microsoft-graph-api

If I use "Graph Explorer" (https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/graph-explorer) with a normal user, I can't read all groups ("Insufficient privileges to complete the operation."). That's the behavior I want.

But if I use "Azure AD Graph Explorer" (https://graphexplorer.azurewebsites.net) with the same user, I can read all groups.

Why ?

**UPDATE**

With my normal user, I can also create a group:
[User in AD](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4BHlT.jpg)

Group creation:
[Azure AD Graph Explorer group creation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6zMgl.jpg)

Comment: In the first link, try to `modify permissions` in the left of it.

Comment: The first uses MS Graph API and the second Azure AD Graph API. Maybe there is a difference between required permissions? And as Joy mentioned, check which permissions are being required by the MS Graph API explorer.

Comment: The behavior of "Microsoft Graph" is correct for me. A normal user should not have access to all groups. If he wants access, he has to ask an administrator.

Answer (score 0):

In the Azure AD Graph Explorer, default access for the user includes Read all directory objects, that's why the normal user can read all groups in Azure AD Graph Explorer.
[image]
For the details, you can read the [Azure AD Graph API permission scope](https://msdn.microsoft.com/id-id/library/azure/ad/graph/howto/azure-ad-graph-api-permission-scopes).

Comment: Thanks Sunny, but with the normal user, I can also create a group.

Comment: Of course, by default, the normal user can create a group and read all groups in Azure AD Graph Explorer.